# Can i use a GIF animation as favicon for my website

Tags: favicon

I need to get some animated effects for favicon on my site. How can i do this?. Help me

Answer (score 3):

It certainly looks like you can. [This blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20071012132256/http://eyestormstudio.com/blog/index.php?p=8) (now only available from the Internet Archive) from 2007 has some details on how to do it.

> Create your animated icon 16 pixels high and wide.

Just add the gif as a favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.gif">
```

> Firefox allows webmasters to use animated favicons and it is likely more browsers will eventually follow suit. While Internet Explorer does not support animated icons in any way, there is an easy way to code things so that you can display an animated favicon in supported browsers and a standard icon for all others.

I'm not sure whether it's a good idea though.